# sql injection - where from

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I am currenty working on a web project, which is getting spammed (comment box).

I know some stuff about sql injections, and I've tried escaping (`mysql_real_escape_string`), the data which could "harm" the database.

But no success.

I've also tried hiding all the forms on site, but the database (comment box) keeps getting spammed.

The data isn't sent directly through url (get or post). So i don't know where else could be the problem. 
Any idea?

EDIT

The textarea (your comment) in form, isn't posted. The form is currently deleted and the spam keeps on going. So because the "send" button isn't pressed, captcha isn't the option.
Commenting is for logged in users only

Thanks, Sebastian

Comment: SQL injections != spam

Comment: Maybe post anything related we can't guess what your code is

Comment: Add CAPTCHA to your comments or restrict to logged in users only.

Comment: Look at your logs to find the offending requests.

Comment: Is the page processing comments ensuring that the user is logged in before running a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mysql_real_escape_string **do not** protect from injections by any means.
there is no words "injection", "harm", "protection" or anything in it's name
this function does string formatting only. A correctly formatted string is invulnerable though, but there are other types that require their own formatting, while string formatting is useless for them.

As for the spam, make a silly honeypot:
Add a field named, say, "city". And tell people **not to fill it**.
Once it filled - it's a bot, discard the message *silently* (do not write silly banners like "Gotcha", "you're bot"). just don't save and keep the rest the same

To answer the edited question:

> The textarea (your comment) in form, isn't posted. The form is currently deleted and the spam keeps on going.

:)
Disable the **form handler** as well
One don't need a form to post comments. it's a form action script which actually does all the job. You can keep the form but to disable posting you have to disable the handler code

Comment: the form (text fields, submit buttons) isn't there anymore, it is deleted from the server. but the database is still getting "spam rows"

Comment: read above... you would have to disable the script that handles the form and writes to the database, as well.

Comment: Ok the form handler was removed, but problem isn't removed. I spam is posting in a set of 3 (3 coments per "attack"). and all 3 coments have the same id in database :/